# Grouping Several Kafka Key Values as single Key Value

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have topic that captures the current position of a video the users are watching.
Events are added every second.

I am looking to save the latest video position all user are at every 30 seconds to limit calls to DB.

Is there a a way to get all of the users latest positions (latest values for all unique keys) so I can perform a single update?

I tried using a KTable but can only seem to get each keys latest record separately (using peek) rather then all keys together.

For example if my topic looks like this:

Input to topic:

Key      Value

```
User1    1
User1    2
User2    1
User1    3
User2    2
User1    4
```

Expected Output together as a single record:

```
User1    4
User2    2
```

I can try to elaborate more if needed (I am new to Kafka world).

Comment: Why do you need a single record? You should be able to iterate all keys from a KTable

Comment: I want the single record to represent a DB update.
So the key represents a group of updates and the value would contain the latest key/values that would be used to perform the update.

Essentially I am looking to use KTable to buffer buy DB updates which I think would work well since it will always have the latest values I need.